# Android - reading list of files fails due to errno=13

Tags: android, file, permissions

I have application which is supposed to read list of files from external storage:

```
<code>
    File x = Environment.getExtrernalStorageDirectory();
    System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] files = x.listFiles();
</code>
```

As an output I get:

```
<code>
    /storage/emulated/0
    fail readDirectory() errno=13
</code>
```

I use isExternalStorageWritable and isExternalStorageReadable from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and they both return true.

My tablet is not rooted, but it is in developer mode. Should I setup somehow the directory first?

Maybe permissions for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are not enough?

Same thing happans when I use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) - ofc. then output contains /storage/emulated/0/Download

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue today. I have noticed that my manifest contained android:maxSdkVersion="18"  attribute.

For example:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />`

It has been resolved by removing this. Hope this helps others too..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String root_sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( root_sd_path + "/" ) ;       
File list[] = file.listFiles();
```

Comment: Such file doesn't exist, I'm getting: fail readDirectory() errno=2

Comment: do you have this on your manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: yes I have setup permissions for READ and WRITE, plus isExternalStorageWritable and isExternalStorageReadable are returning true. Moreover SD card in in /storage/extSdCard and it is also returning errno = 13 while accassing.

Comment: Same issue... still errno=13. I start to susspect, that even thought application has "JAVA" permissions, still Android/Linux permissions are checked by system and when I checked the settings in linux are: drwxrwx--x owner root group sdcard_r

Comment: I'm confused. This application of mine behaves the same when it has the user-permissions or not. Additionally, when I am installing it, it says that it doesn't need any permissions? Shouldn't it say that it requires

Comment: Is it possible, that this is due to the fact that I use AIDE (free version)?

Comment: can you put the part of your manifest file where you have the permissions?

Comment: this permission is only needed in android 18 and bellow!

Comment: <uses-permissions android.name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permissions android.name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 
    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="11" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <inte
   
        </activity>
  
    </application>

Comment: I have Andrid 4.4.2 on samsung galaxy tab 4 wifi

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today. The problem was in my manifest file. I accidentally put the `<uses-permissions>` tag inside the `<application>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but In my case, I don't put the permission code on the AndroidManifest.xml, when I did this, my app run without any error.